# getting a 404 on the courses api request

Tags: express

very basic idea
i have a routes folder and im starting with local data aiming to move to mongodb...
well not until i learn the basics including how to solve this, im getting a 404 when calling fetch for courses on the FE (reactJS axios use effect...) but i dont know whats the issue any ideas?

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const courses = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Course 1',
    description: 'This is the first course',
    instructor: 'John Doe',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Course 2',
    description: 'This is the second course',
    instructor: 'Jane Smith',

  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'Course 3',
    description: 'This is the third course test',
    instructor: 'Jane Smith',
  },
];

router.get('/courses', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(courses)
  try {
    res.json({courses:courses});
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});


router.get('/home', (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    res.send({ message: 'Welcome to the homepage!' });
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const routes = require('./routes/routes');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.use('/', routes);

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error(err.stack);
  res.status(500).send('Something broke!');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

```
export const fetchCourses = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/courses`);
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching courses:', error);
    throw error;    
  }
};
```

FE code use ReactJs

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetchCourses();
        console.log(response.data)
        setCourses(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching course:', error);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

the code is very nooby apologies XD

Comment: backend code seems fine. how are you calling an API from frontend?

Comment: @MuhammadSaqlain thank you for the quick answer, i edited the code to include the FE part, forgot to include this const API_URL = 'http://localhost:3001';
its a useEffect calling the fetchCourses using axios

Comment: cant find anything wrong all is perfect

Comment: paste exact value of API_URL